# Как ограничить максимальную высоту картинки при генерации PDF через FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Использую библиотеку FPDF v. 1.84
При генерации pdf на страницы динамически добавляются картинки. Все они разного размера и пропорций. Получилось ограничить ширину, но вот высоту не могу.
Как обрезать картинку, если её высота слишком большая?

Comment: $pdf-> Image($image,0,0,35,35); - h=35 w=35

Comment: В таком случае картинка сплющивается или растягивается. Мне нужно просто чтобы она не превышала определенную высоту